# connecting to azure storage using access key in azure kubernetes service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage-files

I am using pip package [azure-storage-file-share](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share/) in my application to get the list of files, connection is done using `access_key` for storage.
It is able to retrieve file information when run locally.
When deployed in azure kubernetes service as a docker container.
The application is not able to connect to the storage service.

I understand using a managed identity is more better way. but Should it connect even using `access_key`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> connecting to azure storage using access key in azure kubernetes service.

You can follow these steps to connect an `Azure storage` account to `Azure Kubernetes` using `access key`.

1. Here is the `yaml` file to use the storage secrets.

**storage_secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: storage-secret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: dmVua2F0Njc4
  azurestorageaccountkey: RVA5d1MvdWROVHhSd1BvMGtuU0d6VEhINnJoTENJNHJqeHVCR3ZBczh6dmdxMjh1Y0Z0Y2tmZHNLVHlXN2RuNEVlYWZtRFgwTXdZcytBU3RNR0xFOWc9PQ==
```

> Note: Before applying the `YAML`, convert the storage account name and access key to base 64 using this [tool](https://www.atatus.com/tools/yaml-to-base64)

2. Upload a sample image to `ACR`. I used `NGINX` as an example.

[image]

This `YAML` file to use an access key to mount an `Azure File share` on `AKS`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-azurestorage-test
  namespace: default
spec:  
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: azuretest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azuretest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azuretest
        image: acrname.azurecr.io/sampleimage/nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test
          mountPath: /<fileshare Name>   
      volumes:
      - name: <fileshare Name>  
        azureFile:
          secretName: venkat
          shareName: /<fileshare Name>  
          readOnly: false
```

Save the above code in `.yaml extension` and then run the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f fileshare.yaml
kubectl get deployment
kubectl get deployment -o json
```

The `Storage Fileshare` was mounted to `AKS` after executing the `kubectl apply` command.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is there any other way I dont have to provide secrets in yaml file?